# Maven : install results to Compilation failure

Tags: java, maven

When running the command "mvn clean", it returns a build success but when running "mvn install", it returns Compilation failure. Could you please help me out to trace what causing the error? Thanks in advance.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.725s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 21 17:50:15 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/270M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project Sample: Compilation failure
[ERROR] \Sample\sample\src\main\java\com\sample\services\tests\CuteIntegrationService.java:[51,73] error: cannot access TransformerObjectSupport
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project sample: Compilation failure
\Sample\sample\\src\main\java\com\sample\services\tests\CuteIntegrationService.java:[51,73] error: cannot access TransformerObjectSupport

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
\sample_codeFromGit\sample\src\main\java\com\sample\services\tests\CuteIntegrationService.java:[51,73] error: cannot access TransformerObjectSupport

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I am using eclipse juno IDe, maven3.2.1 and jdk 1.7

Answer (score 3):

- The clean target only deletes the target folders content. Hence no errors there.
- Try `dependency:resolve` to load the dependencies alone.

It should have automatically download dependencies before the compile phase.

- Verify your compile time dependancy at the POM. Post your POM file here, if that didnt work.

Comment: Does your code import org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerObjectSupport or does it depend on any non-public custom class with the same name? Try Project> Clean from Eclipse to see if you can replicate the compile time error on eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Maven has to download jar containing TransformerObjectSupport class.

Probably it is  spring-ws-core-*.jar , check it in .m2e folder

Also check dependencies in pom.xml